# Handling huge float matrices in java

Tags: java, matrix, heap-memory, primitive

I'm currently working on a JAVA project, where i need to create float matrices for the results of an All-pair-Shortest-path algorithm. I'm having a lot of Heap-Memory issues, some of my graph can have more than 700k vertices.
I'm looking for a way to limit memory usage so i can process some of the biggest graphs i have.

I've been searching and found this article :  [Using memory mapped file for huge matrix](http://vanillajava.blogspot.fr/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html)

I did a quick implementation of it, but i don't have enough space on the disk for some of the graphs, and i get a java.io.IOException.

Any suggestion on what i could do ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

*Edit : Performance is not an issue, if i need to leave the app open for hours of computation, it's still better than no computation at all

Comment: If you must handle 700k x 700k dense matrices then you have a deep problem architectural problem right there.  You are talking about 490,000,000,000 `floats` -- that would require about 2TB of storage.  You could consider adding a huge additional disk to accommodate these (no more than a small number at a time), but you are likely to find that performance is terrible.  This problem seems to be looking for distribution over a cluster, or maybe an enormous shared-memory machine.

Comment: If each vertex is around 48 bytes, you will be consuming just 35 MB for them.  If you are having memory problems it is unlikely to be this. I suggest you use a memory profiler to see what is using your memory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: John, I'm working as an intern and don't have access to any hardware upgrade, which is the reason why i'm looking for an implantation solution.

Peter, my memory problems occur only when i try to compute the shortestpath matrix, i don't have any issue with the vertices. If you're talking about the memory mapped file, i've never this type of Objects before so i might have done an error or two, i'll look into it

Comment: A disk stored `(matrixname, i, j, value)` with get/set, indexed by the first three fields. You could start with a database.